# partitioned materialized view in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a partitioned materialized view but its failing
with the error ora-00933

```
create materialized view my_mv
  refresh fast with rowid
  enable query rewrite
 as
select sal_dt ,
sum(sales) sum_sales
from sales
group by sal_dt
partition by range (sal_dt)
interval (numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
(partition p_sal_dt_min values less than (to_date(' 2013-11-18 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=gregorian'))

partition by range (sal_dt)
*
error at line 10:
ora-00933: sql command not properly ended
```

Any ideas what am i missing here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physical properties go before the query. Move the PARTITION BY ... clause just after "enable query rewrite" piece ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm)).

Comment: apologies i couldn't give you credit earlier as i got busy and thought i had marked your answer right